# Should.js chaining multiple assertions on a single property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I've got an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    "uuid": "60afc3fa-920d-11e5-bd17-b9db323e7d51",
    "type": "candy"
}
```

I want to write a test that checks first that the object has the property 'uuid' in the first place, and then that 'uuid' is a specific length (36 chars).

Trying this doesn't work

```
obj.should.have.property('uuid').which.should.have.length(36)
```

It fails with:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected Assertion {
  obj: '60afc3fa-920d-11e5-bd17-b9db323e7d51',
  params: { operator: 'to have property \'uuid\'' },
  negate: false } to have property 'length' of 36 (got [Function])
```

And this (which actually doesn't make syntactic sense anyway - since it would apply to the parent object not the value)

```
obj.should.have.property('uuid').and.be.length(36)
```

Which fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: usergridResponse.entity.should.have.property(...).which.should.be.equal.to is not a function
```

Even this doesn't work:

```
obj.should.have.property('uuid').which.equals('60afc3fa-920d-11e5-bd17-b9db323e7d51')
```

So what's the correct way to chain assertions on the property of an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this could be the better option:

```
var session = {
    "uuid": "60afc3fa-920d-11e5-bd17-b9db323e7d51",
    "type": "candy"
};

session.should.have.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36);
```

Or this if you want to choose `should` twice, but I don't think that this is a proper way (explained bellow).

```
var session = {
    "uuid": "60afc3fa-920d-11e5-bd17-b9db323e7d51",
    "type": "candy"
};

session.should.have.property('uuid').which.obj.should.have.length(36);
```

You can see them working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz2zsoks/

`.an`, `.of`, `.a`, `.and`, `.be`, `.have`, `.with`, `.is`, `.which` are just chainers that don't do nothing.

**Update**

As a response to @denbardadym I'll try to explain why you should not use `should` twice:

- You won't use it twice in natural language, so it's better to don't use it in tests
- Should.js is not intended to be used in that way. You will not find any example of that usage in the library documentation.

Comment: It is not right way to suggest use .should twice - better to explain why it is wrong.

Comment: Ok, already explained. 

But it is also not right way to write an answer without giving an answer ;)

Comment: Also the obj shouldn't be length 36, obj.uuid should be

Comment: @remus The first option I'm giving you works and I guess it has a proper syntactic. The second one is checking the length of the property not the object, I understand it fine. `.obj` is the way to access the property value, if you see my answer I changed the name of your ariable `obj` to `session`.

Comment: Definitely your first suggestion is what I was looking for. And I can also use that with `.equal('...')` (instead of `.with.a.lengthOf`)

Comment: For clarity, I ended up with: `obj.should.be.an.Object.and.have.property('uuid').with.a.lengthOf(36)`

Comment: To try to continue helping: obj.should.be.an.Object is not asserting nothing, you needto use the function (I think that the doc is wrong, if you don't do obj.should.be.an.Object() it will not work) Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1ds5q99/

Comment: Also, I would remove totally the object assertion because in Javascript there are a lot of things that are instances of an Object (like arrays), so anything that can have a property will assert to true if you check if it's an Object.

Answer (score 1):

First statement failed because you call `.should` twice - second time you assert on assertion, it should be:

```
obj.should.have.property('uuid').which.have.length(36)
```

(error message literally sais, that `Assertion {...}` has no property length)

Second statement does not throw for me:

```
obj.should.have.property('uuid').and.be.length(36)
```

(your error message looks like not that assertion fail for you)

Last statement - there is not `.equals` assertion - it should be `.equal`. And it of cause throws for me because `"0320a79a-920d-11e5-9b7a-057d4ca344ba" !== "60afc3fa-920d-11e5-bd17-b9db323e7d51"`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Think I'm making progress. Uuid not matching was a copy fail on my part . `.length` is probably because it's `.lengthOf` instead of `.length`. Will fiddle some more.

Comment: That is ok =). I suggest you for such question use gitter chat for should.js repo, i usually answer faster.